# Loop a if statment through rows

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R so I am asking a basic question.

I have two data frames

Data frame 1 contains matching pairs:

```
Factor1 Factor2
  A       D
  B       E
  C       F
```

Data frame 2 contains the level of different factors in different samples:

```
  Sample1 Sample2
A   10      0
B   10      0
C   0       0
D   0       10
E   0       10
F   0       0
```

I am trying to loop through the first data frame. For each row in data frame 1, if the level of factor1 is larger than 5 in sample 1 and the level of factor 2 is larger than 5 in sample 2, then add TRUE in a third column to data frame 1. Otherwise add FALSE. I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks

```
Factor1 Factor2 if_match
  A       D       TRUE
  B       E       TRUE
  C       F       FALSE
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Is A,B,C... in data.frame 2 a column or row.names ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of columns are the same in the two datasets, use `match` to get the index of rows based on comparing the rownames of 'df2' with that of each column of 'df1', then get the corresponding column value of second dataset, check if it greater than or equal to 5 and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector`

```
df2$if_match <- Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y) y[match(row.names(df2), 
                    x, nomatch = 0)] >=5 , df1, df2))
df2$if_match
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data.frame 2 has row.names equal to the factors in data.frame 1, you can use row.names subsetting :

```
DF1$if_match <- DF2[as.character(DF1$Factor1),'Sample1'] > 5 &
                DF2[as.character(DF1$Factor2),'Sample2'] > 5

> DF1
  Factor1 Factor2 if_match
1       A       D     TRUE
2       B       E     TRUE
3       C       F    FALSE
```

**EDIT :**
Note that data.frame subsetting by row.names uses a partial matching, so for instance `DF['A',]` will find both `'A'` and `'A123'` if present among `row.names(DF)`.
So, if your data can have partially matching factors, I suggest you to use the following code instead (as suggested in the [data.frame subset documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html)) :

```
DF1$if_match <- DF2$Sample1[ match(as.character(DF1$Factor1),row.names(DF2)) ] > 5 &
                DF2$Sample2[ match(as.character(DF1$Factor2),row.names(DF2)) ] > 5
```

---

Code to reproduce your example data :

```
DF1 <- read.csv(text=
'Factor1,Factor2
A,D
B,E
C,F')

DF2 <- read.csv(text=
'Sample1,Sample2
A,10,0
B,10,0
C,0,0
D,0,10
E,0,10
F,0,0')
```